# Вызов метода прототипа по клику js

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой прототип:

```
 ProfileEditor = {

    saveContacts: function (btn) {
        this.validation(params);
        return false;
    },

    validation: function (obj){
        obj.each(function(index, value)){
            var val = $('#' + value);
            if($.trim($(val)).length ! == false ) {
                params_v.value = val;
            }
        });

        if (!isObjectEmpty(params_v)){
            ProfileEditor.sendAjax(params_v);
        }
    },

    sendAjax: function (param){
        $.post("/edit", param, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
              alert('ok');
        });
    }
}
```

И кнопка, вызывающая событие onclick и метод **saveContacts();**

```
<button onclick="ProfileEditor.saveContacts(this)">Сохранить</button>
```

По клику выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ProfileEditor
> is not defined

Как правильно вызвать метод saveContacts?

Comment: у вас не прототип а объект, в смысле ваш метод это просто свойство объекта, не вешайте события в разметке, умоляю. и ещё - у вас там форма ? вешайте на нее события submit а не на кнопу click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var params = var a
```

Ошибка номер 1 ( так у вас ничего не выйдет )

```
var ProfileEditor
```

Ошибка номер 2 (Тут даже скорее не ошибка, а не уместное использование **var** - а это очень важный оператор в js)

```
saveContacts: function (btn) {
        validation(params);
        return false;
    }
```

Ошибка номер 3 (прочитайте про такое незамысловатое слово как **this** и как его использовать в js)

```
ProfileEditor = {

    saveContacts: function (btn) {
        validation(params);
        return false;
    }

    validation: function (obj){
        obj.each(function(index, value)){
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка номер 4 (Чиnайте темы, что такое литеральная нотация и как ей пользоваться в js)

```
obj.each(function(index, value)){
            console.log(value);
        }
```

Ошибка номер 5 (Надеюсь это просто опечатка)

Исправив 5 этих ошибок у вас все заработает!.

Comment: ну я еще раз повторюсь, var лучше оставить, лучше убрать хэндлрер из разметки чем делать глобальную переменную.

Comment: @eicto в данном случае я просто отвечал на вопрос, как поступить в сложившихся обстоятельствах, правильность подхода в моем ответе не рассмативалась:)

Ну а что касается глобально видимости, я к примеру иногда использую такие конструкции для описаний каких-нибудь static функций, типа аналога класса со статичными методами в ООПэшных языка, как java. Не вижу ничего плохого в этом особенно если приложение не большое. Возможно я не прав? но пока каких-то проблем не возникало у меня, как с точки зрения читаемости кода, так и с точки зрания производительности

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно ошибок море - поспешил запостить...Сейчас исправил, но эффект тот-же. При клике на кнопку и вызове метода из прототипа ProfileEditor - завершился с ошибкой.

Comment: Прошу Вас посмотреть на исходный вопрос - он отредактирован. Но проблема не решилась

Comment: obj.each(function(index, value))  - как минимум здесь скобка лишняя

Comment: Ошибка: Uncaught ReferenceError: ProfileEditor is not defined (onclick)

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, http://jsfiddle.net/Zf69C/

Comment: Spasibo, rabotaet, a mojno li v prototipe sozdati localinuiu peremennuiu, dostipnuiu vo vsem ProfileEditor?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk во первых это не прототип, почитайте, о том что такое prototype в js. во вторых переменную задать можно, точно также как функцию пример - "local: null", ну и в третьих, если это у вас форма то лучше действительно повесить событие на submit, как говорили выше.